# Will I lose my on-hand coins or elixir?

Tags: clash-of-clans

What if someone were to attack my base, and let's say I have 80,000 coins on me, if the enemy manages to take out all my coins collector and storage, will the 50% and 20% they take, will result in me losing my coins, when they have the 70% of the coins, will I only have 30% of my coins left for me?

Answer (score 1):

Gold and Elixir
The percentage of Gold/Elixir that can be stolen from storages until TH6 is 20% and is capped at 200,000. At TH7 and up, the percentage that can be stolen drops by 2% at each TH level, to a minimum of 10% at TH11 and above, while the cap increases by 50k at each TH level, to a maximum of 550,000 at TH13.

Gold and Elixir is typically divided evenly between the available storages; it is divided 3 ways for a TH3-TH7, 4 ways for a TH8 and 5 ways for a TH9 or above (this corresponds to how many storages are available at those Town Hall levels). However, division amongst the storages is often more complicated than an even split in most cases (see the Loot Distribution section for more info).

Dark Elixir
The percentage of Dark Elixir that can be stolen from the storage until TH8 is 6% and is capped at 2,000. Starting at TH9, the percentage that can be stolen drops by 1% at each TH level (down to a minimum of 4% at TH10 and above) and the cap goes up by 500, up to a maximum of 4,500 at TH13.

Dark Elixir is typically divided between the Dark Elixir Storage and the Town Hall at a 4:1 ratio at lower Dark Elixir counts, though at higher Dark Elixir counts, the Dark Elixir storage will hold proportionally more of the Dark Elixir than the Town Hall (see the Loot Distribution section for more info).